# Summation function for large integers

Tags: python, math

I am an amateur Python coder trying to find an efficient solution for [Project Euler Digit Sum problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=776). My code returns the correct result but is is inefficient for large integers such as 1234567890123456789. I know that the inefficiency lies in my *sigma_sum* function where there is a 'for' loop.

I have tried various alternate solutions such as loading the values into an numpy array but ran out of memory with large integers with this approach. I am eager to learn more efficient solutions.

```
import math

def sumOfDigits(n: int) :
    digitSum = 0
    if n < 10: return n
    else:
        for i in str(n): digitSum += int(i)
    return digitSum

def sigma_sum(start, end, expression):
    return math.fsum(expression(i) for i in range(start, end))

def theArguement(n: int):
    return n / sumOfDigits(n)

def F(N: int) -> float:
    """
    >>> F(10)
    19
    >>> F(123)
    1.187764610390e+03
    >>> F(12345)
    4.855801996238e+06
    """
    s = sigma_sum(1, N + 1, theArguement)
    if s.is_integer():
        print("{:0.0f}".format(s))
    else:
        print("{:.12e}".format(s))

print(F(123))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Comment: Like most Project Euler problems this one requires you to find a mathematical shortcut. Any solution that requires 1234567890123456789 "things" will never finish.

Comment: Try to break down the sum and see what logically goes together

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is fundamentally a math question, not a programming question. The way to solve the problem of adding up these numbers quickly is to notice that *you do not need to add them* in order to get the correct result - just like you wouldn't if they were all the same number. Please see for example https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Algebra/GaussSummation.shtml.

Comment: I agree that the solution is a math problem and I can get the solution. My question is not about finding a solution, rather, it is more general. I'm looking for opinions and views on how large data sets are handled in Python. For example, how do I handle dictionaries or arrays with 1M+ entries. Is NumPy the only option? Or, are there better libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try solving a different problem.

Define G(n) to be a dictionary. Its keys are integers representing digit sums and its values are the sum of all positive integers < n whose digit sum is the key.  So

```
F(n) = sum(v / k for k, v in G(n + 1).items())
```

[Using < instead of ≤ simplifies the calculations below]

Given the value of `G(a)` for any value, how would you calculate `G(10 * a)`?

This gives you a nice easy way to calculate `G(x)` for any value of x.  Calculate `G(x // 10)` recursively, use that to calculate the value `G((x // 10) * 10)`, and then manually add the few remaining elements in the range `(x // 10) * 10 ≤ i < x`.

Getting from `G(a`) to `G(10 * a)` is mildly tricky, but not overly so. If your code is correct, you can use calculating `G(12346)` as a test case to see if you get the right answer for `F(12345)`.